# Public Suffix List C# parser

Tags: c#, parsing, dns, tld, public-suffix-list

Does anyone have Public Suffix List (getting real domain) parser in c#.

It was available on  code.google.com /p/domainname-parser/ (remove space before p in name) , however project has probably been removed from google code, since I cannot access project folders and source anymore.

Comment: If it was removed I'd guess it was because of a licence dispute - I can't think why else they'd pull an open source project. (Why don't you want to actually link to it - because the project has been removed?)

Comment: [http://code.google.com/p/domainname-parser/](http://code.google.com/p/domainname-parser/)  was original url...  When you click on it, you'l receive google password request. Even after login with my gmail I can't get to source code... Since this is first time I have found a project on code.google.com that requires google login, and no "project removed" or similar is on screen I asked for a source.

Comment: I found it at softpedia: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/DomainNameParser.shtml

Comment: i found a library here https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.PublicSuffix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was just looking for this myself, it seems to still be available -

https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.PublicSuffix

Comment: Documentation is terrible.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get the code in gary's answer to pass the [mozilla test cases](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/test/unit/data/test_psl.txt?raw=1), so hacked these mods together based on the original and the algorithm described [here](http://publicsuffix.org/list/). Hopefully it's of use to someone if the domainname-parser code dissapears from the web.

```
namespace DomainName.Parser
{
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System;

  public class DomainName
  {
    public DomainName(string rawDomainName, string publicSuffix, string registerableDomainName)
    {
      this.RawDomainName = rawDomainName;
      this.PublicSuffix = publicSuffix;
      this.RegisterableDomainName = registerableDomainName;
    }

    public string RawDomainName { get; private set; }

    public string PublicSuffix { get; private set; }

    public string RegisterableDomainName { get; private set; }

    public static bool TryParse(string rawDomainName, PublicSuffixRuleCache ruleCache, out DomainName domainName)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawDomainName) || !rawDomainName.Contains('.') || rawDomainName.StartsWith("."))
      {
        domainName = new DomainName(rawDomainName, null, null);
        return true;
      }

      try
      {
        rawDomainName = rawDomainName.ToLower();

        //  Split our domain into parts (based on the '.')
        //  We'll be checking rules from the right-most part of the domain
        var domainLabels = rawDomainName.Trim().Split('.').ToList();
        domainLabels.Reverse();

        // If no rules match, the prevailing rule is "*"
        var prevailingRule = FindMatchingRule(domainLabels, ruleCache) ?? new PublicSuffixRule("*");

        // If the prevailing rule is an exception rule, modify it by removing the leftmost label.
        if (prevailingRule.Type == PublicSuffixRule.RuleType.Exception)
        {
          var labels = prevailingRule.Labels;
          labels.Reverse();
          labels.RemoveAt(0);

          prevailingRule = new PublicSuffixRule(string.Join(".", labels));
        }

        // The public suffix is the set of labels from the domain which directly match the labels of the prevailing rule (joined by dots).
        var publicSuffix = Enumerable.Range(0, prevailingRule.Labels.Count).Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, i) => string.Format("{0}.{1}", domainLabels[i], current).Trim('.'));

        // The registered or registrable domain is the public suffix plus one additional label.        
        var registrableDomain = string.Format("{0}.{1}", domainLabels[prevailingRule.Labels.Count], publicSuffix);

        domainName = new DomainName(rawDomainName, publicSuffix, registrableDomain);
        return true;
      }
      catch
      {
        domainName = null;
        return false;
      }      
    }

    private static PublicSuffixRule FindMatchingRule(List<string> domainLabels, PublicSuffixRuleCache ruleCache)
    {
      var ruleMatches = ruleCache.PublicSuffixRules.Where(r => r.AppliesTo(domainLabels)).ToList();

      // If there is only one match, return it.
      if (ruleMatches.Count() == 1)
      {
        return ruleMatches[0];
      }

      // If more than one rule matches, the prevailing rule is the one which is an exception rule.
      var exceptionRules = ruleMatches.Where(r => r.Type == PublicSuffixRule.RuleType.Exception).ToList();
      if (exceptionRules.Count() == 1)
      {
        return exceptionRules[0];
      }      
      if (exceptionRules.Count() > 1)
      {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unexpectedly found multiple matching exception rules.");
      }

      // If there is no matching exception rule, the prevailing rule is the one with the most labels.
      var prevailingRule = ruleMatches.OrderByDescending(r => r.Labels.Count).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
      return prevailingRule;
    }
  }

  public class PublicSuffixRule
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Construct a rule based on a single line from the www.publicsuffix.org list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ruleLine">The rule line.</param>       
    public PublicSuffixRule(string ruleLine)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ruleLine) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ruleLine))
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("ruleLine");
      }

      //  Parse the rule and set properties accordingly:
      string ruleName;

      if (ruleLine.StartsWith("*", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        this.Type = RuleType.Wildcard;
        ruleName = ruleLine;
      }
      else if (ruleLine.StartsWith("!", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
        this.Type = RuleType.Exception;
        ruleName = ruleLine.Substring(1);
      }
      else
      {
        this.Type = RuleType.Normal;
        ruleName = ruleLine;
      }

      this.Name = ruleName.Split(' ')[0];

      var labels = this.Name.Split('.').ToList();
      labels.Reverse();

      this.Labels = labels;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public RuleType Type { get; private set; }

    public List<string> Labels { get; private set; }

    public bool AppliesTo(List<string> domainLabels)
    {
      if (this.Labels.Count > domainLabels.Count)
      {
        return false;
      }

      foreach (var position in Enumerable.Range(0, this.Labels.Count))
      {
        if (this.Labels[position] == "*")
        {
          return true;
        }

        if (this.Labels[position] != domainLabels[position])
        {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rule type
    /// </summary>
    public enum RuleType
    {
      /// <summary>
      /// A normal rule
      /// </summary>
      Normal,

      /// <summary>
      /// A wildcard rule, as defined by www.publicsuffix.org
      /// </summary>
      Wildcard,

      /// <summary>
      /// An exception rule, as defined by www.publicsuffix.org
      /// </summary>
      Exception
    }
  }

  public class PublicSuffixRuleCache
  {
    public PublicSuffixRuleCache(string publicSuffixRulesFileLocation)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(publicSuffixRulesFileLocation))
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("publicSuffixRulesFileLocation");
      }

      this.PublicSuffixRules = GetRules(publicSuffixRulesFileLocation);
    }

    public PublicSuffixRuleCache(IEnumerable<string> publicSuffixRules)
    {
      this.PublicSuffixRules = GetRules(publicSuffixRules);
    }

    public List<PublicSuffixRule> PublicSuffixRules { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of TLD rules from the cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<PublicSuffixRule> GetRules(string publicSuffixRulesFileLocation)
    {
      var results = new List<PublicSuffixRule>();

      //  If the cached suffix rules file exists...
      if (File.Exists(publicSuffixRulesFileLocation))
      {
        //  Load the rules from the cached text file
        var ruleStrings = File.ReadAllLines(publicSuffixRulesFileLocation, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
        results = GetRules(ruleStrings);
      }

      return results;
    }

    private static List<PublicSuffixRule> GetRules(IEnumerable<string> publicSuffixRules)
    {
      // Strip out any lines that are a comment or blank.         
      return
        publicSuffixRules.Where(
          ruleString =>
            ruleString.Trim().Length != 0
            && !ruleString.StartsWith("//", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(ruleString => new PublicSuffixRule(ruleString)).ToList();             
    }
  }  
}
```

Unit tests:

```
namespace DomainName.Library.Tests
{
  using FluentAssertions;

  using Xunit;

  using DomainName.Parser;

  public class CheckPublicSuffixTest2
  {
    public bool CheckRegisterableDomain(string domainName, string registerableDomain)
    {
      var ruleCache = new PublicSuffixRuleCache(@"C:\publicsuffix.txt");

      DomainName outDomain;
      if (DomainName.TryParse(domainName, ruleCache, out outDomain))
      {
        return outDomain.RegisterableDomainName == registerableDomain;
      }

      return registerableDomain == null;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestCheckPublicSuffix()
    {
      // Any copyright is dedicated to the Public Domain.
      // http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

      // null input.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain(null, null).Should().BeTrue();

      // Mixed case.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("COM", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("example.COM", "example.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("WwW.example.COM", "example.com").Should().BeTrue();

      // Leading dot.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain(".com", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain(".example", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain(".example.com", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain(".example.example", null).Should().BeTrue();

      // Unlisted TLD.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("example", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("example.example", "example.example").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.example.example", "example.example").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.example.example", "example.example").Should().BeTrue();

      // TLD with only 1 rule.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("biz", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("domain.biz", "domain.biz").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.domain.biz", "domain.biz").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.domain.biz", "domain.biz").Should().BeTrue();

      // TLD with some 2-level rules.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("com", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("example.com", "example.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.example.com", "example.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.example.com", "example.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("uk.com", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("example.uk.com", "example.uk.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.example.uk.com", "example.uk.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.example.uk.com", "example.uk.com").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.ac", "test.ac").Should().BeTrue();

      // TLD with only 1 (wildcard) rule.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("cy", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("c.cy", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.c.cy", "b.c.cy").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.c.cy", "b.c.cy").Should().BeTrue();

      // More complex TLD.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("jp", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.jp", "test.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.test.jp", "test.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("ac.jp", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.ac.jp", "test.ac.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.test.ac.jp", "test.ac.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("kyoto.jp", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.kyoto.jp", "test.kyoto.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("ide.kyoto.jp", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.ide.kyoto.jp", "b.ide.kyoto.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.ide.kyoto.jp", "b.ide.kyoto.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("c.kobe.jp", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.c.kobe.jp", "b.c.kobe.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.c.kobe.jp", "b.c.kobe.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("city.kobe.jp", "city.kobe.jp").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.city.kobe.jp", "city.kobe.jp").Should().BeTrue();

      // TLD with a wildcard rule and exceptions.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("om", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.om", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("b.test.om", "b.test.om").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("a.b.test.om", "b.test.om").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("songfest.om", "songfest.om").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.songfest.om", "songfest.om").Should().BeTrue();

      // US K12.
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("us", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.us", "test.us").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.test.us", "test.us").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("ak.us", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.ak.us", "test.ak.us").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.test.ak.us", "test.ak.us").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("k12.ak.us", null).Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("test.k12.ak.us", "test.k12.ak.us").Should().BeTrue();
      this.CheckRegisterableDomain("www.test.k12.ak.us", "test.k12.ak.us").Should().BeTrue();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll need to review your code, but this looks like a real good work! +1